# Syntax for correctly capturing current user in a trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-8.0

So this worked as a test:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Metrosky_spotters_2020_au` 
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON `Metrosky_spotters_2020` 
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.trnmswid = 5000;
```

Now I'm getting syntax error substituting "5000" with  CURRENT_USER()

per chapter 6.4 MySQL 8.0 reference this would be correct reference...but not allowing the info to be passed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you have found a problem.

> ```
> select CURRENT_USER();
> ```
>
> ```
> | CURRENT_USER()                |
> | :---------------------------- |
> | fiddle_XQKHLETMKAXKBKBXJWXJ@% |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT, user VARCHAR(64));
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_test
> BEFORE INSERT
> ON test
> FOR EACH ROW
> SET NEW.user = CURRENT_USER();
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test (id) SELECT 1;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | user                         
> -: | :----------------------------
>  1 | fiddle_XQKHLETMKAXKBKBXJWXJ@%
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b6fa83497286315495fa8fa2c0e2dca)*

Search the uncorrectness elsewhere.

Comment: So the above adds to a new table - but I need the user name (which is a 4 digit number) to flow to column: Modifying  trigger above
SET NEW.trnmswid = CURRENT_USER();; 
doesn't populate trnmswid  field 

column: trnmswid  type:  int(5) unsigned zerofill NULL

Comment: @Mike *I need the user name (which is a 4 digit number)* From [documentation]:(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) ***CURRENT_USER, CURRENT_USER()** Returns the user name and host name combination for the MySQL account that the server used to authenticate the current client.* If you need in some 4-digit number you must specify where it must be taken from and how it must be identified there.